# Get current directory of a Finder window from a cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, accessibility, applescript

I'm trying to get a current directory of a finder window that is in focus from another cocoa application that is running in a background. I know that it can be done using an applescript like:

```
tell application "Finder"
try
  set dir to (the target of the front window) as alias
on error
  set dir to startup disk
end try
end tell
```

However I was wondering whether there is some more generic way of doing it either using the accessibility API or some other UI scripting with perhaps `System Event`?

I tried attributes like `NSAccessibilityDocumentAttribute` or `NSAccessibilityURLAttribute` but none is set. From other mostly document based applications this works pretty well, but not for finder nor for terminal.app.

Comment: @regulus6633 (I can add a comment directly to your post so I add it here) Thanks to your post, but similarly to Brian Webster, my question was not how to run applescript from within cocoa, but whether these is a generic way how to get a current working directory out of an application like finder app or terminal app using either accessibility API or applescript. Right now I think all these have to be handled as a special case.

Answer (score 4):

```
    // this is the finder
    FinderApplication * finder = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Finder"];
    // get all the finder windows
    SBElementArray * finderWindows = finder.FinderWindows;
    // this is the front window
    FinderWindow * finderWindow = finderWindows[0];
    // this is its folder
    FinderFolder * finderFolder = finderWindow.properties[@"target"];
    // this is its URL
    NSString * finderFolderURL = finderFolder.URL;
    NSLog(@"front window URL: %@", finderFolderURL);
```

Comment: Will all of this work under sandboxing as well? I remember reading about restrictions when it comes to Apple Events/Scripting

Comment: You may need to add the appropriate entitlements…

Comment: Where is FinderApplication, FinderWindow and FinderFolder defined? There are no results returned when searching in Xcode documentation or on the Apple Developer website. Also, the SBApplication setup line returns a SBApplication instance not a FinderApplication one. At least it does on my Xcode 8.0...

Comment: FinderApplication, FinderWindow and FinderFolder are defined by the scripting dictionary of the Finder application. There's a command line tool converts that into an include file for your project to use… read the ReadMe.txt file that's part of this project: <https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SBSystemPrefs/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008043-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_5>

Comment: Yes SBApplication returns a SBApplication… it's the base class of FinderApplication… you may typecast it to FinderApplication or just message it directly.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Scripting Bridge framework](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html), that's probably going to be the easiest way to get the info you want directly from your Cocoa application.

Comment: As I don't have votes left, I will virtually give a +1 to the answer.

Comment: I guess I should have expressed myself better. I know how to execute applescript from within cocoa, the question was whether there is a way how to get the current directory of a finder accessibility API or if there is some more generic way to obtain this information.

Answer (score 1):

@nkuyu, I just saw your comment that you know how to run an applescript... but for others who don't (and might stumble onto this post) I'll explain.

It's easy to run an applescript from objc using NSApplescript. And if you return a string from your applescript it's even easier to get a result because you can get the "stringValue" from the NSAppleEventDescriptor. As such I return "posix paths" from the applescript. Note that NSApplescript is not thread-safe so in multi-threaded apps you must take care to always run it on the main thread. Try this...

```
-(IBAction)runApplescript:(id)sender {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getFrontFinderWindowTarget) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void)getFrontFinderWindowTarget {
    NSString* theTarget = nil;
    NSString* cmd = @"tell application \"Finder\"\ntry\nset dir to the target of the front window\nreturn POSIX path of (dir as text)\non error\nreturn \"/\"\nend try\nend tell";
    NSAppleScript* theScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:cmd];

    NSDictionary* errorDict = nil;
    NSAppleEventDescriptor* result = [theScript executeAndReturnError:&errorDict];
    [theScript release];
    if (errorDict) {
        theTarget = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error:%@ %@", [errorDict valueForKey:@"NSAppleScriptErrorNumber"], [errorDict valueForKey:@"NSAppleScriptErrorMessage"]];
    } else {
        theTarget = [result stringValue];
    }
    [self getFrontFinderWindowTargetResult:theTarget];
}

-(void)getFrontFinderWindowTargetResult:(NSString*)result {
    NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
}
```